# Is there a way to simplify the follow code?

Tags: css, styling

I am wondering if there is a simplified version of the following code.

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tihbj.png)

I am trying to adjust the background-image URL because as I am shrinking the background image, the image shrinks as well which made the entire page show the white border on the bottom. As shown below:

[Another snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5QkE.jpg)

Instead of writing 3 different lines of code based on the max-width, is there a way to write them all at once and have the same effect? Also, I am open to other suggestions if this is not the best way to go.

Thanks all!

Comment: Add `work url` or add your code ??

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better site

Comment: Please keep in mind that Code Review needs the actual code to be __in__ your question. Have a look at [their help-center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before you post there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following on your background image's CSS styling:
`background-size: cover;` 
`background-repeat: no-repeat;`